# JPanel Positioning

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, positioning, layout-manager

Why isn't my minimap panel at the right of the JFrame?

My code seems to be right but I must be making a stupid mistake.  Please help me out :)

```
    private static void loadResources() {
    minimap.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(minimapWidth, minimapHeight));
    minimap.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(minimapWidth, minimapHeight));
    minimap.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(minimapWidth, minimapHeight));

    panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    minimap.setBackground(Color.red);
    panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    panel.add(minimap);
    minimap.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    Character.createCharacter();
    frame.add(panel);
}
```

[image]

Comment: learn all about LayoutManagers, best starting with the online tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki here. BTW:  [don't use setXXSize, ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Answer (score 0):

You set the panel layout to be CENTER. Then you add the minimap, so the minimap is centered too.

By calling

```
minimap.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
```

You just say that all elements inside the minimap (nothing in this case) should be positioned on the right relative to the minimap rectangle. So if you add an element, let's say a grey rectangle, to the minimap you should see the red rectangle in the center of the JFrame and the gray rectangle on the right inside the red rectangle.

You may try

```
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
```

But this may change other element position.